# React transform transition group issues. Want to do an easy animation, but doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

Did everything by documentation http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition

Here is a codesandBox, everything what I want is on hovering the header -> header__curtain slides down.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-platform-x9cug?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it isn't really an answer but will recommend you to use framer-motion which is a bit more intuitive and easy to understand while also keeping your code pretty clean unlike react transition group.